# Name of a theorem in probability theory

Tags: probability, probability-theory, analysis, reference-request, weak-convergence

Let $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of $\mathbb{R}^d$ valued random variables defined on a probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$. Write $\mu_n$ for the law of $X_n$. Assume there exists a Borel probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that $\mu_n \to \mu$ weakly as $n \to \infty$. Then there exists a random variable $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^d$ with law $\mu$.

The point of the theorem is that $X$ is defined on the very same probability space $\Omega$.

Edit:
I was able to find the following proof, which is great.
[Weak convergence of random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519999/weak-convergence-of-random-variables?rq=1)

Does this theorem have a name? If yes, what is the name of this theorem? Since this result looks useful, is it mentioned in any textbooks?

Comment: The Wikipedia article on "Skorohod's representation theorem" has references.

Comment: The statement is slightly different than Skorohod's representation theorem. The probability space and $X_n$'s here are predefined.

Comment: @kimchilover : The Skorohod representation says that there exists an $(\Omega, F, P)$ for which the result holds (some $(\Omega, F, P)$ might not work because they are not big enough).  Here $(\Omega, F, P)$ is given but the $X_n$ variables suggest that space is indeed big enough.

Comment: I **think** the asserted fact is true. If you define $Y_n = \arctan(X_n)$ then $\{Y_n\}$ is a sequence of bounded random variables. You would want a version of Bolzano-Wierstrass for a subsequence to have some type of  limit.   The answer is certainly known by certain mathematicians but, as it seems to me, it can only be worked out by piecing together partially stated theorems about way-more-general things, most of which use loaded terminology.  See discussion on Prohorov theorem here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/896968/bolzano-weierstrass-theorem-for-random-variables

Comment: By "piecing together partially stated theorems" I mean statements of the form "these random variables converge in distribution" without a statement of whether or not there is another random variable on the same probability space that has the limiting distribution.